# How to Register Durable External Service in Consul

Tags: consul

I am registering an external service in consul through Catalog API  http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/catalog/register with a payload as follows :

```
{
  "Datacenter": "dc1",
  "Node": "pedram",
  "Address": "www.google.com",
  "Service": {
    "ID": "google",
    "Service": "google",
    "Address": "www.google.com",
    "Port": 80
  },
  "Check": {
    "Node": "pedram",
    "CheckID": "service:google",
    "Status": "passing",
    "ServiceID": "google",
    "script": "curl www.google.com > /dev/null 2>&1",
    "interval": "10s"
  }
}
```

The external service registers successfully and I see it in the list of registered services, but after a while it disappears. It seems that it's got unregistered automatically.

I am running the consul in -dev mode.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I should register external services in separate node. My application's local services are getting registered in a node named

```
"Node": "pedram"
```

when I register external services in this node, they will be get removed automatically.

But when I register my external services in a new node, all the new external services are get registered durably and ready to be used as all other local services.

my new payload is as follows :

```
{
  "Datacenter": "dc1",
  "Node": "newNode",
  "Address": "www.google.com",
  "Service": {
    "ID": "google",
    "Service": "google",
    "Address": "www.google.com",
    "Port": 80
  },
  "Check": {
    "Node": "newNode",
    "CheckID": "service:google",
    "Status": "passing",
    "ServiceID": "google"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is excepted behavior. In Consul [Anti-Entropy docs](https://www.consul.io/docs/internals/anti-entropy.html)

> If any services or checks exist in the catalog that the agent is not aware of, they will be automatically removed to make the catalog reflect the proper set of services and health information for that agent. Consul treats the state of the agent as authoritative; if there are any differences between the agent and catalog view, the agent-local view will always be used.

In your settings, the agent in the host 'pedram' didn't aware of the service register. so the anti-entropy strategy removes the service.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using -dev mode, except for testing/playing around. for your health check, I'd recommend not using a     `"script": "curl www.google.com > /dev/null 2>&1",`
Instead I'd recommend using a http health check:
`"http": "https://www.google.com",`

More about health checks is available here: https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html

Also, you should probably move to HTTPS (on port 443) if you can.

it also might help to save this as a .JSON file, and let consul read it as part of it's startup, as I'm guessing you want this to be a long-running external service.  You can do that with a command like:
`/usr/local/bin/consul agent -config-dir=/etc/consul/consul.d`
and every .json file in `/etc/consul/consul.d/` will be read as part of it's config.  If you change the files, `consul reload` will restart.

I'd make those changes(not run in dev mode, etc) and see if the problem still exists. I'm guessing it won't.

Comment: Thanks Zie for your participation. I found the answer and I will share it.